# Create folder and subfolder in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

I have a path, for example, "L:\BACKUP\FIRST\". I want to create folders automatically with path. I use a batch file to do my backup so i want to make that with the same batch.

Comment: If it's easier to make that into SQL script, i can integrate a function into it. Because my batch file launch an SQL script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `mkdir` is all you'll need for this.

for example

```
mkdir L:\BackUP\First\
```

Comment: Thank i didn't know that this function could make it ;)